# Is it safe to install a third party high capacity battery into my iPhone 5S?

Tags: battery, iphone, customization, third-party

I stumbled upon [this battery on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K0SCT56) and I was wondering if it'd be safe to install it into my iPhone 5S, assuming it's actually compatible.
[image: 2680mAh Chinese battery]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you consider "safe" to mean and whether you care about receiving Apple warranty support once you open the device?

Comment: I don't care about Apple's warranty. By safe I mean do I run the risk of damaging the phone's hardware? Thanks.

Comment: The golden battery with the red 2680mAh sticker looks very authentic ;)

Comment: Ironically, right?

Answer (score 3):

No it is not safe.

Not for technical reasons -- That is impossible to judge -- but look at the seller's profile on amazon. They have thousands of items for sale, yet they have a total of *two* customer ratings; one rating one star the other two stars (out of five)!

This looks very much like a scammy outfit that changes its name when it gets bad reviews. Run away.

Also: shipping time 20 to 30 days?!?

Answer (score 0):

The golden battery with the red 2680mAh sticker is NOT 2680mAh.
The original Apple iPhone 5S battery is 1560mAh 3.8V 5.92Whr. 
If you look at the golden battery label it says 3.8V 5.92Whr  which is 1560mAh

If you take the gold cover of underneath you will see it's just the same as the original iPhone 5S battery 1560mAh 3.8V 5.92Whr